# How to extract IP Address in Spring MVC Controller get call?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ip-address

I am working on Spring MVC controller project in which I am making a GET URL call from the browser -

Below is the url by which I am making a GET call from the browser -

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/testweb/processing?workflow=test&conf=20140324&dc=all
```

And below is the code in which the call comes after hitting at the browser -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "processing", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ProcessResponse processData(@RequestParam("workflow") final String workflow,
    @RequestParam("conf") final String value, @RequestParam("dc") final String dc) {

        System.out.println(workflow);
        System.out.println(value);
        System.out.println(dc);

        // some other code
    }
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Now is there any way, I can extract IP Address from some header? Meaning I  would like to know from which  IP Address, call is coming, meaning whoever is calling above URL, I need to know their IP Address. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Try using Spring AOP and handling HttpServletRequest.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271807/how-to-inject-httpservletrequest-into-a-spring-aop-request-custom-scenario

Answer (score 193, accepted):

The solution is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "processing", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ProcessResponse processData(@RequestParam("workflow") final String workflow,
    @RequestParam("conf") final String value, @RequestParam("dc") final String dc, HttpServletRequest request) {

        System.out.println(workflow);
        System.out.println(value);
        System.out.println(dc);
        System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());
        // some other code
    }
```

Add `HttpServletRequest request` to your method definition and then use the Servlet API

Spring Documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) said in

> 15.3.2.3 Supported handler method arguments and return types

```
Handler methods that are annotated with @RequestMapping can have very flexible signatures.
Most of them can be used in arbitrary order (see below for more details).

Request or response objects (Servlet API). Choose any specific request or response type,
for example ServletRequest or HttpServletRequest
```

Comment: Thanks Koitoer for the help. One quick question, suppose if the call is coming from Load Balancer instead of specific machine then this will work as well? I guess not..

Comment: No it wont, but there are some configuration in the loadbalancer that can send the IP as they does not exist, probably this is your case

Comment: Check probably load balancer can send those values in a header, so consider using getHeader method of HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Koitoer It works perfectly!! But there is any other way rather than HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Also you could use HttpSession but then extract HttpServletRequest lol.. Actually I think the question is there is another way to send the IP information in the request, if the answer is positive there could be another ways to extract, but use the API in the common way I don't even know any other option . If you add the IP in the headers, you can extract them and read the IP info, but this is a customization of the headers, that you can extract with HttpSession object

Comment: I am getting wrong ip address (0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1) if the request from postman. Do anyone have idea, how to get ip address even if the request from the postman?

Comment: I'm also getting 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

Comment: This is deprecated.

Comment: @DipeshGandhi were you able to resolve your problem? I am also getting `(0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1)` through postman. Were you able to get pubic IP address?

Answer (score 143):

I am late here, but this might help someone looking for the answer. Typically `servletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` works.

In many cases your application users might be accessing your web server via a proxy server or maybe your application is behind a load balancer.

So you should access the [**X-Forwarded-For**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) http header in such a case to get the user's IP address.

e.g. `String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");`

Comment: Note that `X-Forwarded-For` is generally a comma-separated list of ips, with each proxy in the chain adding the remote address it sees to the list. So a good implementation would generally have a list of trusted proxies and "skip" those ips when reading this header from right to left.

Comment: how to get ip address as 111.111.111.111/X

Comment: Note that e.g. Tomcat has `RemoteIpValve` that parses `X-Forwarded-For` header and sets it on the `HttpServletRequest`, so that `servletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` returns correct end-user IP address.

In Spring Boot it can be enabled via `server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=X-Forwarded-For` application property

Comment: Can't `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header be spoofed by the client? Wouldn't it be safer to only assume `X-FORWARDED-FOR` valid if `getRemoteAddr()` belongs to a whitelist of credible  proxy service providers?

Comment: Spring boot is able to automatically resolve the forwarded IP address for you. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126518/how-to-cope-with-x-forwarded-headers-in-spring-boot-2-2-0-spring-web-mvc-behin) for details.

Answer (score 59):

I use such method to do this

```
public class HttpReqRespUtils {

    private static final String[] IP_HEADER_CANDIDATES = {
        "X-Forwarded-For",
        "Proxy-Client-IP",
        "WL-Proxy-Client-IP",
        "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR",
        "HTTP_X_FORWARDED",
        "HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP",
        "HTTP_CLIENT_IP",
        "HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR",
        "HTTP_FORWARDED",
        "HTTP_VIA",
        "REMOTE_ADDR"
    };

    public static String getClientIpAddressIfServletRequestExist() {

        if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() == null) {
            return "0.0.0.0";
        }

        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        for (String header: IP_HEADER_CANDIDATES) {
            String ipList = request.getHeader(header);
            if (ipList != null && ipList.length() != 0 && !"unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ipList)) {
                String ip = ipList.split(",")[0];
                return ip;
            }
        }

        return request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
}
```

Comment: where do i use it ?

Comment: It is a static class, it uses the name of the class and the method

ip = HttpReqRespUtils.getClientIpAddressIfServletRequestExist();

Comment: For those who are wondering why return `0.0.0.0` when `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() == null`, see [0.0.0.0 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0).

Comment: Add `if (ip.equals("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1")) ip = "127.0.0.1";` before `return ip` statement in the above code to make it IPv4 complaint.

Answer (score 19):

You can get the IP address statically from the `RequestContextHolder` as below :

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
        .getRequest();

String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I was using Nginx in front of my application with the following configuration:

```
location / {
     proxy_pass        http://localhost:8080/;
     proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
     add_header Content-Security-Policy 'upgrade-insecure-requests';
}
```

so in my application I get the real user ip like so:

```
String clientIP = request.getHeader("X-Real-IP");
```

Comment: Thank you sir. It's a graceful solution that helped me.

Answer (score 7):

See below. This code works with spring-boot and spring-boot + apache CXF/SOAP.

```
    // in your class RequestUtil
    private static final String[] IP_HEADER_NAMES = { 
                                                        "X-Forwarded-For",
                                                        "Proxy-Client-IP",
                                                        "WL-Proxy-Client-IP",
                                                        "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR",
                                                        "HTTP_X_FORWARDED",
                                                        "HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP",
                                                        "HTTP_CLIENT_IP",
                                                        "HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR",
                                                        "HTTP_FORWARDED",
                                                        "HTTP_VIA",
                                                        "REMOTE_ADDR"
                                                    };

    public static String getRemoteIP(RequestAttributes requestAttributes)
    {
        if (requestAttributes == null)
        {
            return "0.0.0.0";
        }
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getRequest();
        String ip = Arrays.asList(IP_HEADER_NAMES)
            .stream()
            .map(request::getHeader)
            .filter(h -> h != null && h.length() != 0 && !"unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(h))
            .map(h -> h.split(",")[0])
            .reduce("", (h1, h2) -> h1 + ":" + h2);
        return ip + request.getRemoteAddr();
    }

    //... in service class:
    String remoteAddress = RequestUtil.getRemoteIP(RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes());
```

:)

Answer (score 6):

Below is the Spring way, with `autowired` request bean in `@Controller` class:

```
@Autowired 
private HttpServletRequest request;

System.out.println(request.getRemoteHost());
```

Comment: This could cause issues with concurrent use of the controller across multiple threads. Only singletons should be injected into `@Controller` instances using `@Autowired`. Otherwise, you must use `@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` on the controller class to ensure that a new instance of the controller is made with every request. This is less efficient, but is a workaround if you must inject something as a property to the controller class.

Answer (score 6):

Put this method in your BaseController:

```
@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
protected String fetchClientIpAddr() {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())).getRequest();
    String ip = Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")).orElse(request.getRemoteAddr());
    if (ip.equals("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1")) ip = "127.0.0.1";
    Assert.isTrue(ip.chars().filter($ -> $ == '.').count() == 3, "Illegal IP: " + ip);
    return ip;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private static final String[] IP_HEADER_CANDIDATES = {
            "X-Forwarded-For",
            "Proxy-Client-IP",
            "WL-Proxy-Client-IP",
            "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR",
            "HTTP_X_FORWARDED",
            "HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP",
            "HTTP_CLIENT_IP",
            "HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR",
            "HTTP_FORWARDED",
            "HTTP_VIA",
            "REMOTE_ADDR"
    };

    public static String getIPFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String ip = null;
        if (request == null) {
            if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() == null) {
                return null;
            }
            request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        }

        try {
            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(ip))
            return ip;

        for (String header : IP_HEADER_CANDIDATES) {
            String ipList = request.getHeader(header);
            if (ipList != null && ipList.length() != 0 && !"unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ipList)) {
                return ipList.split(",")[0];
            }
        }

        return request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
```

I combie the code above to this code work for most case. Pass the `HttpServletRequest request` you get from the api to the method

Answer (score 1):

In my case request.getRemoteAddr() contains the IP address of system from which user is trying to access the application.
and in case, if I am running my application on localhost or 127.0.0.1 it is returning "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using this piece of code:

```
private String getRemoteAddr(HttpServletRequest req) {
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(req.getHeader("X-Real-IP"))) {
        return req.getHeader("X-Real-IP");
    }
    return req.getRemoteAddr();
}
```