# Obtain IP Address from client's HTTP Request using Java

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, ip-address

Am using Spring 4 MVC for RESTful Web Services on Tomcat 7.

Was wondering if an external client sends a HTTP request, is there a way to obtain the particular client's IP Address within the server side layer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877350/how-to-extract-ip-address-in-spring-mvc-controller-get-call

Comment: Also be aware of the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Comment: @Chrylis - Why should I be aware of the X-Forwarded-For header? Thanks for the precautionary head's up.

Comment: Because if you're behind a firewall or load balancer (the usual case), the IP address you get from the HTTP connection won't be the client's.

Comment: @PacificNW_Lover could you close this question by accepting an answer? if you don't it will remain open and people will think you still need help.

Answer (score 3):

```
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails
```

A holder of selected HTTP details related to a web authentication request.

Indicates the TCP/IP address the authentication request was received from.

```
String ipAddress = ((WebAuthenticationDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()).getRemoteAddress();
```

If you are testing on a local application, your ip address will be `"0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"`

Answer (score 1):

Simple POJO

```
public static InetAddress getClientIpAddr(HttpServletRequest request) {  
    String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");  
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {  
        ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");  
    }  
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {  
        ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");  
    }  
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {  
        ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");  
    }  
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {  
        ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");  
    }  
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {  
        ip = request.getRemoteAddr();  
    }  
    try {
        return InetAddress.getByName(ip);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        return null;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Clever, but not very DRY.

Comment: please specify `UnknownHostException`, rmi or net ?