# Spring RESTful API getting client information

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-rest

Iv'e been using this guide:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service
to create a RESTFul web service, my issue I am having is that I do not know how to get information such as the clients IP address, is this possible with this API?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract IP Address in Spring MVC Controller get call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877350/how-to-extract-ip-address-in-spring-mvc-controller-get-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Spring Rest Controller you can add HttpServletRequest to get client info.

**Example**

```
@GetMapping("/dummyurl")
public Boolean syncWithServNow(HttpServletRequest httpReq, @RequestParam("username") String username) {
    System.out.println(httpReq.getRemoteAddr());  // Line 1
}
```

In most cases it will work. In case like 
url is accessed by web server over a proxy server or has a load balancer this will do.

```
httpReq.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
```